# Exception occurs outside function only when deployed outside debug environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, exception, entity-framework-5

I'm using `ASP.Net MVC 3` to create a single sign-on provider for my company. Everything worked just fine until I started deploying to the server. Every production server I deploy to, this `Exception` will occur:

```
    [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   UniQ.SSO.Controllers.LoginController.Index(String requestToken, String callbackUrl) +89
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +123
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +727142
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +727142
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +309
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +727076
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +334
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +52
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

I tried all kinds of different things. I tried copying all local dependencies with the project or deploying to different servers. And after that didn't work I tried remote debugging but it just stops at the `function` declaration and tells that the exception has occurred at that point.

```
public ActionResult Index(string requestToken, string trustid, string challenge, string callbackUrl)
```

Also Google hasn't been much of a help so far, so does anyone know what's happening or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to include the code for that method.  The error is happening on line 89, so what is the code there.

Comment: It is harder to tell exactly without all the available information. It looks like in the LoginController.Index there is something accessing a null variable which causes to throw this exception. Also check the values that has been passed by the requestToken, callbackUrl.

Comment: @JohnKoerner That's not right. The `+89` is referring to the IL code offset not an actual line number. In a stacktrace `LoginController.cs:89` would refer to line 89 in the LoginController.cs file. This because a "Compiled" .net assembly doesn't have the original source files in it.

Comment: @Raj The Exception does not occur within the function. I know this because I wrapped the code within the function in a `try ... catch` which would output the exception details in text format upon occurrence. Though I still get the Runtime Error page explaining the Exception instead of a print out of the Exception.

Comment: @Feanaro You're right, I read it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments gave me the idea of uploading the debug symbols to the server. This actually gave me a  file and line number on the Runtime Error page and helped me out with solving my problem.

Thank you, @JohnKoerner and @Raj for inspiring the idea!

The problem originated from an `HTTPModule` that I made, one of the things it was supposed to do is initialize the environment. Somehow the module didn't get instantiated. Since it didn't execute anything the environment became incomplete and unstable thus originating in a `NullReferenceException` a bit later on in the execution.

I just had to also register the `HTTPModule` in the `System.WebServer` namespace of the`web.config` file. This has to do with the managed pipeline settings on your application pool. When you have it set to `integrated` you also need to register your `HTTPModule` in the `System.WebServer` namespace. After that the problem was fixed and the SSO platform is up and running now.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add type="UniQ.SSO.Module.OAuthAuthenticationModule" name="OAuthAuthentication"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```